# how to merge array and json object using javascript

Tags: json

How do I merge these 2 JSON variables?

```
var j1 = {"a":{"hello":"test"},"b":['array']};
var j2 = {"b":{"hi":"world"}};

$.extend(true,{},j1,j2) does not work it removes my ['array'] value
```

i want a result like this

> "b": {"hi":"world"},['array']

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with `"b": {"hi":"world"},['array']`? Should b be an object or an array. `b:{"hi": "world",['array']}` or `b: [{"hi": "world"} , ['array']]` ?

Comment: Your desired result is a mutant object which does not exist in the real world. What were you planning to do with it?

Comment: I am planning to store it in $('body').data() then access later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you

```
function merge (obj1, obj2) {
   var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1)); // Clone object
   for(var key in obj) {
      if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         obj[key] = [obj[key], obj2[key]];
      }
   }

   return obj;
}
```

example :

```
var j1 = {"a":{"hello":"test"},"b":['array']};
var j2 = {"b":{"hi":"world"}};
obj = merge(j1, j2);


/* Result :

{
   "a": {
      "hello": "test"
   },
   "b": [
      [
         "array"
      ],
      {
         "hi": "world"
      }
   ]
}

*/
```